# Merge OCX with .NET EXE

Tags: .net, dll, merge, ocx

Is there any tool, commercial or freeware, that allows merging OCX files with .NET executable?
I know it's possible to make an isolated OCX reference, but that's not sufficient in my case, I need to get a single exe without installation requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, VMware ThinApp allows this.

Answer (score 1):

A .ocx is an unmanaged DLL that contains COM servers, ActiveX controls typically.  It cannot be merged into a .NET assembly.  You will have to replace those controls with, say, custom Windows Forms controls to get ahead on your plan.